# Variable item only displaying one line

Tags: c#

For each of the lines with the specific keyword, I want to print it to a `TextBox`.
But once I got it to read the text file and select the lines with the keyword and add it to a List, it only displays the first line of the list.

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    var text = client.DownloadString("https://foo.com/list");

    File.WriteAllText("C:/ProgramData/oof.txt", text);

    string searchKeyword = "Name";
    string fileName = "C:/ProgramData/oof.txt";
    string[] textLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    foreach (string line in textLines)
    {
        if (line.Contains(searchKeyword))
        {
            results.Add(line);
        }
        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Move your `foreach (var item...` block out of the `foreach (string line..` block.

Comment: you're overriding the text of your `richTextBox1` on each iteration, use `+=` to concatenate

Comment: I wonder how you manage to write in that path, `/` character is not the windows directory separator.

Comment: @bradbury9 .net runtime dont care, it knows what u mean

Answer (score 1):

your loop at the end just sets the text to the last item.

```
      foreach (var item in results)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = item;
        }
```

not clear what you want but how about this.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
          foreach (var item in results)
            {
                sb.Append(item);
                sb.Append " ";
            }

                richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```